# Python check time interval (perform actions in 1, 2, 3, 10 milliseconds)

Tags: python, time, intervals

I'm looking to check when an event occurs, make a set of actions that are apart by a certain time.

```
if (volt>3):
    oldtime=curtime
    curtime = t
    diff = curtime-oldtime
    if time.time == curtime + (difference/3):
        do something
        temptime=curtime+(difference/3)
    if time.time == curtime+(temptime+(difference/10):
        do something
        temptime == (temptime+(difference/10)
    if .... etc
```

So whenever my voltage hits a threshold, I want to send of a series of events  that have very specific timings. I'm pretty sure the way it's set up now is not efficient or accurate. I'm streaming data to a graph, and don't want to pause while waiting for these intervals (and to check the voltage about every 10ms.

I'm not sure what to put in place of the if statements, to make it act as a when time.time = timeWanted: do thing

Also will I need to do multithreading for this? (haven't experienced that yet)

From research I'm seeing windows is only accurate to 10ms with timers. Should I consider running on a different OS or using a different language as well?

Comment: are they in sequence?

Comment: The events should be in sequence

Comment: so 1,2,3 10ms apart?

Comment: That's correct. The sequence is a ratio between two peaks of voltage detections.

Comment: Where do you get t from? This code will not run.

Comment: You would definitely need threads.

Comment: T is a global time variable, initialized at 0. A new T value comes in when I grab my voltages. volt, T = device.getVoltage(register).

I should rephrase my question as more of a, how should I set up a sequence of timed events accuratley, as opposed to a if time==desiredTime

Comment: I'm asking about t, not T; just to be precise;.). However, the function should return a voltage according to its name, so why assigning to a time-variable. Just jusdging by the names. Oh, and douse more expressive names for global variables, if you think you really need them anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I meant t not T; the voltage comes with the time it was collected (t), this function is from the library of the device that I'm pulling the voltage from.

Comment: Are you sure you need *strict* timings? You don't need it to produce a smooth animated graph. [tag:real-time] is entirely different beast from an ordinary programming on common well-known OSes. Almost unrelated but fun talk: [Hard Real-time Python, or, Giant Robots of Doom](http://www.pyvideo.org/video/481/pyconau-2010--hard-real-time-python--or--giant-ro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need accurate timing, I would strongly recommend to use a Language without garbage collection like C or C++. If you can tolerate some deviations from an exact raster, you might go fine with Python, however.

Regarding the resolution of time.time, pls see the corresponding page in the documentation. There is a difference ther between Windows and Linux. Where it says for the latter, time.time() has higher resolution, for Windows is should be time.clock(). The latter I cannot confirm, as I do not have a Windows box available.

In any way, it might be better to use a threading/multiprocessing framework, as the CPU will be exessively busy when polling timeslots.

Ah, and I would recommend to get time() only once and compare with some tolerance. Otherwise you will loose timeslots eventually. A good technique is to calc the time of the next timeslot and compare for time() <= next_slot. This way, even if you miss the exact time, you will eventually hit shortly after.

**Edit:**
You need to maintain the next timeslot seperately for each interval. Also, to avoid long-term deviation, use absolute times, not deltas:

```
curr_time = time.time()

if curr_time >= interval1_next_time:
    interval1_next_time += INTERVAL1_TSLOT
    if curr_time >= interval1_next_time:
        # we lost a full timeslot, so slowly adjust (can also report)
        interval1_next_time += INTERVAL1_TSLOT
    ....
if curr_time >= interval2_next_time:
    interval2_next_time += INTERVAL2_TSLOT
    ....
```

Comment: <= actually should do the trick. I'll try pre calculating when each step of the sequence should occur, But won't I still need to compare it with a new call to time.cock() to check when time has occurred/passed?

Comment: Why should you? just get the time of the current cycle once, then test for each slot. However, this "busy polling" is bad practice. You should really try to find a better solution. Perhaps sleep() would even help, but I have not worked with that so far. If I have something regular to input to the PC, I use an external microcontroller which handles the real-time stuff.

Comment: sleep will block so that is not an option

Comment: That depends on the rest of the program. If it's only purpose is to check do something every few ms, sleep would be fine, if it can wait that small be period.Just use the GCD of all time slots. (which would be 1ms for the example).

Comment: I'll provide more context on my pseudo snippet there.
It's part of a pulse detection device, and when your pulse occurs, the voltage increases momentarily. After I receive the voltage(I check wehn it passes threshold of 3v), I want to set a series of voltages on other registers in the device (do something) at specific timings after the pulse.

Comment: Hmm... where yo you get the data from? With timing constraints like that, I would think having the device which does the measuring doing the processing itself and just buffering the data and stream it to the PC. Hate to say, but an Arduino/etc. might be a good start (The RasPi will not, for similar reason like the PC). In any way, you should be aware that Python is not real-time capable, be it threading or polling. Even as such, a normal PC might even not guarantee 1ms reaction time (sic!), as the SMI may block it for some time once in a while. That depends on the BIOS actually. ...

Comment: ... Not sure, however, if UEFI is better here. (Yes, that is very deep inside). All depends on the actual application. however. I do that stuff professional, so I might be overcautions.

Comment: How do you get the data into the PC, anyways? USB? High-Speed/Full-Speed? Hmm... if the data arrives at a regular interval, you might onsider select.poll() or select.select() (I think Windows does not support poll())

Comment: I'm getting the data via high speed USB. I think I have it all working now except getting time difference (diff = time.time() - oldtime) doesnt seem to work. Once I have it working as accurately as I can in python, I might change to a more appropriate language

Comment: @user3524785 : If you think the answer was helpful, please consider to upvote and/or accept it. I added some code how the compare should work

Answer (score 0):

You say you are streaming to a graph.  If you update the graph 5-10 times a second or so, it looks pretty much continuous to a human viewer.  So I would consider this possibility: your graphics environment presumably has some sort of timer tick, or if not you might look at the standard library threading.Timer.  When a data point arrives, you add it immediately to a data buffer.  But you only update the graph when the timer fires.  You never worry about missing any data.  I do this sort of thing all the time and it works well in practice.

Comment: So, slow down my graphs update frequency/accuracy, and put my resources into gathering the correct data, and putting it into a buffer for my graph to update with?

Comment: I do not think the Graph processing would be such a problem. Unless you wait for vsync, of course.

Comment: Yes, you slow down the update frequency but not its accuracy in any sense,  The graph is *accurate* since you aren't throwing data away.  Humans can't see the graph change 100 times a second anyway, and presumably human viewers is why you're doing this.  When you watch TV the screen isn't updating 100 times a second, but you don't complain that it's "inaccurate."